# Facebook account kit in Android

Tags: android, account-kit

How to implement facebook account kit for verifying phonenumbers in Android?Their official documentation seems to be weird.Please help.Also what are the attributes need to be given in styles.xml ?

My LoginActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


}

public void onLoginPhone(final View view) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AccountKitActivity.class);
    AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder =
            new AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder(
                    LoginType.PHONE,
                    AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.CODE); // or .ResponseType.TOKEN
    // ... perform additional configuration ...
    intent.putExtra(
            AccountKitActivity.ACCOUNT_KIT_ACTIVITY_CONFIGURATION,
            configurationBuilder.build());
    startActivityForResult(intent, APP_REQUEST_CODE);
}





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this AccountKitSimpleSample as a guide to add the necessary pieces if the docs are harder to read through: https://github.com/fbsamples/account-kit-samples-for-android/tree/master/samples/AccountKitSimpleSample

Are you planning to do any theming? You don't need to update your styles unless you want to customize the UI further than the basic flow.